# How to create a gradient button with an image and text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a Flutter project and I want to create a button with a gradient background that includes both an image and text. However, I am not sure how to achieve this.

I have tried to make it like this image:

[image]

I have tried using the MaterialButton widget and setting its shape property to a RoundedRectangleBorder with gradient color, but I cannot figure out how to add the image and text to the button.

Can someone please provide me with an example of how to create a gradient button with an image and text in Flutter? Additionally, is there a way to customize the gradient colors of the button?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Stack` widget with 3 children (from lowest to highest):

1. `Image`
2. `Container` with `decoration.gradient` of semi-transparent colors
3. `Text`

If you wish you could wrap entire `Stack` in `ClipRRect` to add rounded corners.

To add button behaviour, you could use custom `GestureDetector` or `InkWell`

Answer (score 0):

Desired Code:

```dart
class ReusableButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ReusableButton({
    super.key,
    required this.onTap,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.title,
    required this.gradientColors,
  });

  final void Function() onTap;
  final String imageUrl;
  final String title;
  final List<Color> gradientColors;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: onTap,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              width: 200,
              height: 120,
              child: Image.network(
                imageUrl,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: gradientColors,
                ),
              ),
              width: 200,
              height: 120,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: Text(
                title,
                style: const TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    ReusableButton(
      onTap: () {},
      imageUrl: 'Your image URL...',
      title: 'Your title...',
      gradientColors: <Color>[
        Colors.red.withOpacity(0.7),
        Colors.green.withOpacity(0.7),
        Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
      ],
    ),
    ReusableButton(
      onTap: () {},
      imageUrl: 'Your image URL...',
      title: 'Your title...',
      gradientColors: <Color>[
        Colors.red.withOpacity(0.7),
        Colors.green.withOpacity(0.7),
      ],
    ),
    ReusableButton(
      onTap: () {},
      imageUrl: 'Your image URL...',
      title: 'Your title...',
      gradientColors: <Color>[
        Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
        Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.7),
      ],
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to make Gradient Color reusable.

Comment: I updated the code. Is it right now?